# Error with matrix assignment

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

Good evening to all,

I would like to affect values of a matrix B to others differents matrix C.

Then i try this code:

```
B=imread("deformation_somb.jpg");

xc=pixel_x1; 
yc=pixel_y1;
% where [nr,nc,channels]= size([B])
% pixel_x1=(nc/2) & pixel_y1=(nr/2);
j=nr-yc;
i=xc;
i_c=1;
j_c=1;
C_horizontale_droite=[];
C_horizontale_gauche=[];
C_verticale_haut=[];
C_verticale_bas=[];
i_nouveau_h=i;
i_nouveau_b=i;
j_nouveau_d=j;
j_nouveau_g=j;

while(i_nouveau_h!=nr-1 || i_nouveau_b!=0 || j_nouveau_g!=0 || j_nouveau_d!=nc-1)
    C_horizontale_gauche(1,j_c,:)=B(i,j_nouveau_g,:);
    C_horizontale_droite(1,j_c,:)=B(i,j_nouveau_d,:);
    C_verticale_haut(1,j_c,:)=B(i_nouveau_h,j,:);
    C_verticale_bas(1,j_c,:)=B(i_nouveau_b,j,:);
    i_nouveau_h = i_nouveau_h+1;
    i_nouveau_b = i_nouveau_b-1;
    j_nouveau_d = j_nouveau_d+1;
    j_nouveau_g = j_nouveau_g-1;
    j_c=j_c+1;
endwhile

distance_pixel_gauche_centre = find(C_horizontale_gauche=C_horizontale_droite!=0)
distance_pixel_droite_centre = find(C_horizontale_droite=C_horizontale_gauche!=0)
distance_pixel_haut_centre= find(C_verticale_haut=C_verticale_bas!=0)
distance_pixel_bas_centre= find(C_verticale_bas=C_verticale_haut!=0)
```

But for the first affect of matrix :

```
C_horizontale_gauche(1,j_c,:)=B(i,j_nouveau_g,:);
```

I have an error message :

```
error : LG : Subscript indices must be either positive integers less than 2^31 or logicals.
```

Then i verify indices they are positive. I give you an example :

For an image 700*700 RGB, nr=nc=700.
Then j=700-350=350,  i =350
So, `j_nouveau_g=350`. 
Thus, the first expression should sent to Octave this one:

```
`C_horizontale_gauche(1,1,:)=B(350,350,:)`
```

... Well.. Why octave send me an error?

Thx for your answers.

Best Regards

Julien

Comment: Quick glance: you will need all the conditions of the while loop to be true, so replace `||` with `&&`?

Comment: Are you sure the size of your image is dividable by 2 on both directions?

Comment: Thx a lot! I replace "or" by "and" the programm work, but one more thing :

All matrix are formed by 0 or 1 value... Where is the problem? My two matrix correspond to two RGB image :/